# Peewee - Model with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, peewee

I am using peewee in python with sqlite. Being a novice in all of these, i need some help with setting up the models in peewee the correct way.

I have three models: Shot, Asset and Task.

Shots and assets can have multiple tasks. Task names has to be consistent, for instance, a Shot and an Asset can both have a different task named 'anim'. I have to track each task's parent.

I first tried setting up the models this way (relevant code):

```
class Shot(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

class Asset(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

class Task(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()
    shot = ForeignKeyField(Shot, null=True, backref="shot_tasks")
    asset = ForeignKeyField(Asset, null=True, backref="asset_tasks")
```

This works and i can do:

```
for task in shot.shot_tasks: #or asset.asset_tasks
    print task.name
```

Then i didn't like it for some reason and tried this:

```
class Task(BaseModel):
    name = CharField()

class ShotTask(Task):
    shot = ForeignKeyField(Shot, backref='tasks')

class AssetTask(Task):
    asset = ForeignKeyField(Asset, backref='tasks')
```

which i think is the same thing basically, but this way, i can name my backrefs 'tasks' and i can do:

```
for task in shot.tasks: #or asset.tasks
    print task.name
```

So, my question is: is there a better way? (I'm sure there is)